# why are capacitors often not labeled using engineering notation ? (1-999)

Tags: capacitor

i see schematics with values such as .01uF among others... why out of all components are these not labeled using engineering notation

Comment: I thought  micro (u),  nano (n) and all were engineering notation (as opposed to scientific notation)

Comment: To be pedantic, .01uF should probably be labeled as 10nF.

Comment: thats exactly my point , .01uf is 10nf but i often see it labeled as .01 which is not engineering notation (1-999)

Comment: Because it is easier to say "everything is µF" and then not write µF all over the place?

Comment: I think this has cropped up before.

Comment: In the old days it was generally pF and µF. As the SI system became more widespread nF was more widely used. I like the 2n2, 4µ7, notation myself as it avoids errors due to missing the decimal point.

Comment: Many schematics comes with a footnote, "all capacitance are in micro Farads unless otherwise stated"...  Now you should understand.

Comment: Anyway, schematics are often not really following any special conventions, as designed and drawn by engineers(in the best case) of different levels. so you can find much weird stuff in them..

Comment: It's hard for dyslexic and sleep deprived to reliably distinguish `u` from `n`.  Especially when reading schematic upsdide-down.  `</humor>`

Comment: @NickAlexeev: That may be part of why its a `µ` rather than a `u`. Hectofarad caps will not figure in most people's schematics.

Comment: Nanofarads (and even picofarads) are a relatively recent invention.  When I started in electronics, capacitors were either uF or uuF, so a schematic showing 0.01uF may have been drawn by an older engineer.

Comment: Interestingly, if you look at [capacitors on DigiKey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/capacitors/ceramic-capacitors/131083), they don't list values in `nF`.  In their capacitance selection list, 10000pF is followed by 0.011uF.

Comment: @Peter Bennet, pF was in common use in the sixties, at least for RF applications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a matter of history, sadly. Capacitors where built well before the International System of measurement (SI) was established and some prefixes weren't used so much (e.g. nano).

For example, usually capacitors only used *microfarad* (sometimes written as \$MFD\$) and *picofarad* as units, this latter often written as micromicrofarad (\$\mu\mu F\$). Therefore \$10nF\$ could only be written as either \$10,000 pF\$ or \$0.01 \mu F\$.

Combine this with the need to encode other information on the smaller packages of the time (e.g. tolerance), and you end up with a metric ton of different encoding schemes, some more obscure than others.

Since old habits are hard to die, even in modern industry, the markings on the caps follow, in some way, the old tradition, where nanofarads "didn't exist".

Answer (score 2):

The history of this is probably bound up in the technology of early capacitors. In the early days, capacitors were

1. Electrolytic or oil-filled (generally larger than 1uF)
2. Mica or NP0 (and other controlled tempco) ceramic types or air (some pF to hundreds of pF)
3. Paper or film types, generally ranging from maybe 0.01uF  to a few
   uF.

It probably seemed easier at the time for the engineers of old to use uF for all but RF applications, where pF were more appropriate.